# Displaying text pages in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have problem with textpages.

TextPages model

```
class TextPages extends Model
{
    protected $quarded = [];
    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'enable', 'system', 'page_type', 'page_type2', 'page_type3', 'page_type4', 'page_type5', 'id_category_page', 'id_category_page2', 'id_category_page3', 'id_category_page4', 'id_category_page5', 'id_categories_of_photos', 'author_add', 'author_update', 'title_on_the_list', 'visible_on_the_top_menu', 'visible_on_the_left_menu', 'visible_on_promo_box', 'date', 'hideData',  'dateToShow', 'title', 'description', 'keywords', 'short_content', 'content', 'url_address'];
}
```

Schema:

```
Schema::create('text_pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->boolean('enable')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('system')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('page_type')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('page_type2')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('page_type3')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('page_type4')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('page_type5')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('id_category_page')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('id_category_page2')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('id_category_page3')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('id_category_page4')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('id_category_page5')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('id_gallery')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('author_add')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('author_update')->default(0);
            $table->string('title_on_the_list', 200);
            $table->boolean('visible_on_the_top_menu')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('visible_on_the_left_menu')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('visible_on_promo_box')->default(0);
            $table->date('date');
            $table->string('file', 160)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('hideData')->default(0);
            $table->date('dateToShow')->nullable();
            $table->string('title', 200);
            $table->string('description', 155);
            $table->string('keywords', 155);
            $table->longText('short_content')->nullable();
            $table->longText('content')->nullable();
            $table->string('url_address', 160)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        });
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'FrontendController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/index', 'FrontendController@index')->name('index');
Route::post('/acceptUserAge', 'FrontendController@acceptUserAge')->name('acceptUserAge');
Route::get('/p/{slug}', 'FrontendController@txtPages')->name('txtPages');

// access only fro user with role USER
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'BackendController@index')->name('adminHome')->middleware(['CheckRole:user,userPremium,userCompany,userSponsor,UserGuest']);
});

// access only fro user with role ADMIN
Route::get('cms/', 'CMSController@index')->name('indexAdmin');
Route::get('cms/login', 'CMSController@loginAdmin')->name('loginAdmin');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'cms', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/adminLoginHistory', 'CMSController@adminLoginHistory')->name('adminLoginHistory')->middleware(['CheckRole:admin,telemarketer,receptionist,adminCompany'])->middleware('verified');
    Route::get('/paymentRegister', 'CMSController@paymentRegister')->name('paymentRegister')->middleware(['CheckRole:admin'])->middleware('verified');
    Route::match(['GET'], '/paymentRegisterEdit' . '/{id}', 'CMSController@paymentRegisterEdit')->name('paymentRegisterEdit')->middleware(['CheckRole:admin'])->middleware('verified');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

Currently, I use route to display text pages:

```
Route::get('/p/{slug}', 'FrontendController@txtPages')->name('txtPages');
```

Website address: name.com/p/page-name

I need to do a routing for pages, but without this "/ p" in the URL - I would like to reach the url for text pages: name.com/page-name

Pages are dynamically created in CMS.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create new url which also works same as `/p/{slug}` then you can create new route after this route.

Below is the sample of this

```
Route::get('/p/{slug}', 'FrontendController@txtPages')->name('txtPages');
Route::get('/{slug}', 'FrontendController@txtPages')->name('txtPages');
```

Here will be the url for both

```
www.domain.com/p/page-name
www.domain.com/page-name
```

try this solution.

Comment: you already created that url
`Route::get('cms/', 'CMSController@index')->name('indexAdmin');` That's why this will not request on that url which you want.

Comment: yes, but this route: Route::get('cms/', 'CMSController@index')->name('indexAdmin'); is not text page - this is admin panel

Comment: it doesn't matter that your url is for admin or frontend. if you are creating two routes with same urls then last executed route will execute. In your case, same thing is happending. if you want to separate your admin cms then add prefix `admin` with that to differentiate it from your text page url.

Comment: which routs are the same for me? I have something like this: Route :: group (['prefix' => 'cms', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

Comment: one route which your defined like this `Route::get('cms/', 'CMSController@index')->name('indexAdmin');` and other which we suggested `Route::get('/{slug}', 'FrontendController@txtPages')->name('txtPages');`. In our suggested route. if you pass `cms` as slug value then this route is also looks like this `Route::get('cms/', 'CMSController@index')->name('indexAdmin');`. do you getting my point?

Comment: Now I understand. How can this be modified to work properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194583/discussion-between-lakhwinder-singh-and-trafficker).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove "p" from your route as folow:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'FrontendController@txtPages')->name('txtPages');
```

Comment: Both routes are diffrenet for "'txtPages'" you can access using "www.domain.com/page-slug"

Comment: you thing about something like this: www.domain.com/super-holiday-in-poland-123 ? Where 123 is page id? what will the route look like for such a structure?

Comment: For example your page slug is  "test1" then you can brouse that page with "www.domain.com/test1".